# Paypal mark $0 due invoice as paid

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, invoice

I have created an invoice through API total due amount is $0, when I try to mark this invoice as paid since nothing to pay but in the invoice it is showing partially paid. Here is my invoice 
[image]
Could someone help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: That image is awfully oversized once opened and far to small to be readable without opening, any chance you could modify it?

Comment: @lix image cropped, now it should be readable.